# My custom javascript function is "not a function"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I wrote a small .js file that has 3 functions in it for easy in-site cookie management. Here is the source for that file:

```
// Make Cookie
function Bake(name,value) {
var oDate = new Date();
oDate.setYear(oDate.getFullYear()+1);
var oCookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + ';expires=' + oDate.toGMTString() + ';path=/';
document.cookie= oCookie; 
}

// Read Cookie
function Eat(name){
    name = name.toLowerCase();
var oCrumbles = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<oCrumbles.length;i++)
{
    var oPair= oCrumbles[i].split('=');
    var oKey = decodeURIComponent(oPair[0].trim().toLowerCase());
    var oValue = oPair.length>1?oPair[1]:'';
    if(oKey == name)
        return decodeURIComponent(oValue);
}
return '';
}

// Delete / Void Cookie
function Burn(name){
Bake(name,'');
}
```

I put that .js file into my "/models" folder on Cloud9. In my index.js I do have the line: `var OCookie = require('../models/oatmealcookie');` to include my custom "library". However, still in index.js, I attempt to call the `OCookie.Bake('test','testvalue');` before a redirect, and an error comes up on the page as `TypeError: OCookie.Bake is not a function`. Any help as to why it's not able to recognise my function as a function?

Comment: You're not exporting anything from the module.

Answer (score 3):

If that is your whole file, you aren't exporting any of your functions through `module.exports`.  Effectively, your file is run once, and `Bake`, `Eat`, and `Burn` are declared as functions for the module but no other module can use them.

You would need something like:

```
module.exports = {
    Bake: Bake,
    Eat: Eat,
    Burn: Burn
};
```

So that other modules can use your functions.

Comment: That did the trick! Now all I get is a `document is not defined` error.. Oh joy. Do you know a quick solution to that?

Comment: @dec0mpiled Well, there isn't really a `document` in node.js.  `document` is for browser code.  Are you using [browserify](http://browserify.org/)?

Comment: I am not, but I will give that a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `export` your functions so that node.js recognises them when you `require` them.

See here: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/ for example.

```
var exports = module.exports = {
    // Make Cookie
    'Bake': function (name,value) {
        var oDate = new Date();
        oDate.setYear(oDate.getFullYear()+1);
        var oCookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + ';expires=' + oDate.toGMTString() + ';path=/';
        document.cookie= oCookie; 
    }

    // Read Cookie
    'Eat': function (name){
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        var oCrumbles = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<oCrumbles.length;i++)
        {
            var oPair= oCrumbles[i].split('=');
            var oKey = decodeURIComponent(oPair[0].trim().toLowerCase());
            var oValue = oPair.length>1?oPair[1]:'';
            if(oKey == name)
               return decodeURIComponent(oValue);
        }
        return '';
    }

    // Delete / Void Cookie
    'Burn': function (name){
        Bake(name,'');
    }
}
```

By convention though, you would start your function names with lower case.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `exports.Bake = Bake` at the end of the module.